# Why the button coincide with the view in the layout?

Tags: android, layout, view

I want to draw three buttons and a view of a keyboard in the screen. I use constraintlayout to draw the three buttons. However, I found that the three buttons coincide with the view. I wonder how I can sperate them. I have changed to height and the weight of the button, but it does not work. I wonder whether I need to change the constraintlayout to linearlayout.
Here is the code of the three buttons:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/functional_buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp">

     <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/Connect_buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/connect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="connect"
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/send"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="send"
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/receive"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/connect" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/receive"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="receive"
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/send" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the code of the keyboard view:

```
<com.example.magickeyboard.View.MyKeyboardContainer
    android:id="@+id/keyboard_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_container_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_container_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_container_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_container_4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</com.example.magickeyboard.View.MyKeyboardContainer>
```

This is the layout:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfViz.jpg)

Comment: How about changing parent's layout_height to 50 or bigger? 30 is smaller than children's height 50.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer helped me solve my problem!@AIMINPAN